# Referrer URL in Safari Browser - not available?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, safari

I have been trying to retrieve the 'referrer URL' when a visitor visits a page on my site.

It works when user uses Chrome, IE, Firefox but not Safari.

I  am retrieving the referrer URL in a servlet that is on the landing page on my site: *getReferrerURL(httpRequest).*

I am extremely puzzled why only Safari does not play ball w.r.t referrer URL - can anyone point me in a correct direction?

Comment: What does the code for `getReffererURL(HttpServletRequest)` look like?

Answer (score 2):

A browser can either natively or by a plugin be configured to disable or even change the `referer` request header. You have totally no control over this from the server side on. The `referer` header should at highest be used for logging and statistics only, not to perform business logic. Whatever functional requirement you thought to solve by checking the `referer` header should most likely be solved differently if you want to make it to work independently from the browser configuration.

Comment: Thank you - yes, that can be a potential case as well. After much debugging, the culprit was found to be the Cisco ACE load balancer - the load balancer was cutting off headers under certain scenarios. Many hours spent over the weekend but solution found :)